# img-resposive doesn't work

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap 3 in the latest release - `3.3.4` - and unfortunately the `.img-responsive` class isn't working properly.
I tried everything, even `.col-md-12` along with `.img-responsive` and nothing.

**HTML:**

```
<header class="container" id="container">
  <div class="row">
    <section class="col-md-3">
        <a href="#">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="..." />
        </a>
    </section>
    <section class="col-md-9">
      <p>something else...</p>
    </section>
  </div>
</header>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    height: 60px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

You can see the live preview [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/zka07fma/8/light/).

@edit

The image is over the container - the red part - that is the reason for the question, `.img-responsive` was supposed to resize the image to make it fit, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete `height: 60px;`

You only need:

```
#container {    
    background-color: red;
}
```

Image has height 150px, but #container has 60px.

Comment: But the size must to be 60%, wasn't `.img-responsive` supposed to resize the image?

Comment: In that case you don't need responsive website. You can set .img-responsive to have height: 60px.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfect. Here my pen http://www.bootply.com/Dka4RjELYK. Have you check your links and script references?